# Migrations files not created in dockerized Django

Tags: python, django, docker, django-migrations

I've made changes to a model in a Django app and need to apply migrations to the database. I'm new to Docker, so this is giving me problems. I've been able to `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but migration files aren't being created, so I can't push my code to production because of the missing migration files. I think this is because I'm running `makemigrations` while connected to the Docker container.

If I try to `makemigrations` without being connected to a running container, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 228, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 205, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 393, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 387, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 87, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 105, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 292, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in has_table
    self.connection.cursor()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 267, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 228, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 228, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 205, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/andrew/Desktop/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Since I'm able to successfully migrate while connected to a running container, is there a way I can get it to produce migration files for me, that I can add to git? Or do I need to figure out how to run `makemigrations` from outside of Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into using bind mounts to connect the migrations folder inside your container to the folder on your local machine. That way, when you run the makemigraions command in the container, the migration files should be reflected locally too

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: I ended up mounting a host directory as a volume inside my container, then running the makemigrations command from inside the volume.