# Dockerized django container not producing local migrations file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, django-migrations

## Question

I am a beginner with docker; this being the first project I have set up with it and don't particularly know what I am doing. I would very much appreciate if someone could give me some advice on what the best way to get migrations from a dockerized django app to store locally

---

### What I have tried so far

I have a local django project setup with the following file structure:

```
Project
   .docker
      -Dockerfile
   project
      -data
         -models
            - __init__.py
            - user.py
            - test.py
         -migrations
            - 0001_initial.py
            - 0002_user_role.py
      ...
      settings.py
      ...
   manage.py
   Makefile
   docker-compose.yml
...
```

In the current state the migrations for the test.py model have not been run; so I attempted to do so using `docker-compose exec main python manage.py makemigrations`. This worked successfully returning the following:

```
Migrations for 'data':
  project/data/migrations/0003_test.py
    - Create model Test
```

**But produced no local file**. However, if I explore the file system of the container I can see that the file exists on the container itself.

Upon running the following:

```
docker-compose exec main python manage.py migrate
```

I receive:

```
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'data' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I was under the impression that even if this did not create the local file it would at least run the migrations on the container.

Regardless, my intention was that when I run `docker-compose exec main python manage.py makemigrations` it store the file locally in the `project/data/migrations` folder and then I just run `migrate` manually. I can't find much documentation on how to do this; the only post I have seen suggested bind mounts ([Migrations files not created in dockerized Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828593/migrations-files-not-created-in-dockerized-django)) which I attempted by adding the following to my `docker-compose` file:

```
 volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data/migrations
        target: /var/lib/migrations_test
```

but I was struggling to get it to work and following from this I had no idea how to run commands through this volume using docker-compose and I was questioning whether this was even a good idea as I had read somewhere it was not best practice to use bind mounts.

### Project setup:

The `docker-compose.yml` file looking like so:

```
version: '3.7'

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  ENV: 'DEV'
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'project.settings'

  DATABASE_NAME: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_USER: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_HOST: 'postgres'

  CELERY_BROKER_URLS: 'redis://redis:6379/0' 


volumes:
  postgres:

services:
  main:
    command:
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      target: main
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - dev.env 
    networks:
      - default
  

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.6
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '25432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    command: postgres -c log_min_messages=INFO -c log_statement=all
  
  wait_for_dependencies:
    image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies 
    environment:
      SLEEP_LENGTH: '0.5'
  
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '16379:6379'


  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      target: main
    command: celery -A project worker -l INFO
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
    volumes:
      - .:/code/delegated
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    networks:
      - default
  
  beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile 
      target: main
    command: celery -A project beat -l INFO 
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
    volumes:
      - .:/code/delegated 
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

Makefile:

```
build: pre-run
build: 
    docker-compose build --pull

dev-deps: pre-run
dev-deps:
    docker-compose up -d postgres redis
    docker-compose run --rm wait_for_dependencies postgres:5432 redis:6379

migrate: pre-run
migrate:
    docker-compose run --rm main python manage.py migrate

setup: build dev-deps migrate

up: dev-deps
    docker-compose up -d main
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.2 as main

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt 

RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . ./

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash app
RUN chown -R app:app .

USER app

EXPOSE 8000
```

---

### Follow up based on diptangsu-goswami's response

I tried adding the following:

```
 volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\dev\Project\project
        target: /code/
```

This creates an empty directory in my `Project` folder; named `C:\dev\Project\project` but the app doesn't run as it cannot find the `manage.py` file... I assumed this was because it was in the parent directory `Project` and tried again with:

```
 volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\dev\Project
        target: /code/
```

But the same problem occured. Why is it creating the empty directory? surely it should just be binding the existing directory with the container directory? Also using this method, would I need to change my `Dockerfile` to not copy the codebase to the container in the first place and just mount it on instead?

Comment: Can you try to throw in your entire code as a volume? Not just the migrations folder.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Thanks for your response, I have tried to build on this and left a couple of questions in an edit on the main post if you don't mind taking a look :)

Comment: Do you have a github repo for this? I do not have much idea about this but I've used a similar thing for flask (alembic) migrations.

Comment: I don't unfortunately @DiptangsuGoswami . No worries though, I seem to have fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding the following to my 'main' service in my docker compose:

```
volumes:
      - .:/code:delegated
```